# c++ string.find() on specific values

Tags: c++, regex, string, assert

I'm using string.find() inside an ASSERT statement for to try and match a couple different pieces of text.  The tests fail when i run them.  Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong. My attempts are below.

here is an example the professor gave us
example:

```
Coffee
16
0.95
10

TS_ASSERT(string::npos != tmpstr.find("Coffee\t\t10\t9.5"));//this works
```

end example

```
Sausage-large
11.10
9

TS_ASSERT(string::npos != tmpstr.find("Sausage-large\t11.10\t9"));  //fails



Fries-large
Remember to salt a lot
2.35
20

TS_ASSERT(string::npos != tmpstr.find("Fries-large\tRemember to salt a lot\t2.35\t20")); //fails

stringstream outThing;
        printSummary(outThing, allProdList);
        string tmpstr = outThing.str();
        TS_ASSERT(string::npos != tmpstr.find("Fries-large\nRemember to salt a lot\n2.35\n20"));
        outFile << tmpstr;
        stringstream outThing2;
```

Comment: The question is, how is the string even produced? (It's also a very strange thing to assert...)

Comment: my understanding is that it is just checking to see if the specified string is tempstr

Comment: `printSummary` would be relevant too. But the lines following the assertion are not. - "my understanding is that it is just checking to see if the specified string is tempstr" - No, that would be the equality operator.

Comment: npos is -1 (sort of) so this assert passes when npos != value of the find statement.  it returns positive when it finds what im looking for therefore the test should pass when i find the string. Right?

Comment: npos should be more like `string::size_type(-1)` (max value of an unsigned type). It returns index of the start of the substring if it is found. If you are getting `npos` then either the search string is not there (and how you produce tmpString is relevant) - or, if you are really unlucky, you have undefined behavior somewhere messing up a substring search here.

Comment: What really **is** in those strings? Can't you print them out (or inspect in the debugger, which would show you the whitespace)? Note that the `Coffee` example is quite far from what is being asserted.

Comment: see my question again. I just added what the prof gave us.  What is his assert statement checking?

Comment: whoops, i need to re-edit the coffee example. its supposed to look like the other ones i provided

Comment: Your Coffee example gives numbers 16, 0.95 and 10, whereas the assert contains 10 and 9.5. How this passes is beyond me, but, to see what's happening, inspect the actual data in the debugger.

Comment: yeah I didn't understand it either. Thanks for you help.

Comment: It's possible 10 is the amount, and 9.5 is the price of this amount. The professor's example seems to involve a computation, your tests don't. - You must have some idea what each of the lines of input are supposed to mean and what you are supposed to do with this input. - Until then you are asking why a string with unknown contents does not contain an arbitrary string.

Answer (score -1):

`\t` is not a line separator. try `\n` (linux & unix) or `\r\n` (windows) like

```
TS_ASSERT(string::npos != tmpstr.find("Sausage-large\n11.10\n9"));
```

Comment: There is no "line separator" in C++.  `'\n'` is the line terminator.  Regardless of the platform.  (And why does everyone assume that he's looking for a new line, and not a tab?')

Comment: @JamesKanze: because he wrote that on separate lines.

Comment: the professor gave us an example using tabs. I'm going to add it to my question